# Moving polygon feature to be centered on given point using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to automate a process with inputs of:

1. Multipart polygon geometry
2. Four points - which are the actual center points of the four small rectangles within the larger polygon

How can I move the polygon to align with the four points using PyQGIS?

My first attempt was to start with the center points and construct the polygons around them, calculating the orientation of the points and rotating the polygons accordingly (see below), but I'll be receiving different polygons (with varying complexity) and hard-coding the dimensions will be too cumbersome. My next thought is to calculate centroids of those inner rectangles, but then I don't know how to snap them to the actual center points. I don't necessarily need the code, but a general approach would be helpful.

```py
layer=my_layer
if not layer:
    print ("Layer failed to load!")
#loop through features
points = layer.getFeatures()
metrics={}
d=QgsDistanceArea()
for point in points:
    #calculate pairwise distances and bearings
    compares = layer.getFeatures()
    for compare in compares:
        geom1=point.geometry().asPoint()
        geom2=compare.geometry().asPoint()
        dist=d.measureLine(geom1,geom2)
        bear=d.bearing(geom1,geom2)
        metrics.update({dist:bear})
    break
#sort dictionary and extract third value, which is the bearing of vessel in radians
i=1
rad=[]
for j in sorted (metrics):
#    print ((j, metrics[j]), end =" ") 
    if i == 3:
        rad.append(metrics[j])
    i+=1

features = layer.getFeatures()
for feature in features:
    # retrieve every feature with its geometry and attributes
    # fetch geometry
    geom = feature.geometry()
    geomSingleType = QgsWkbTypes.isSingleType(geom.wkbType())
    if geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
        ptx=geom.asPoint().x()
        pty=geom.asPoint().y()
        pol = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[QgsPointXY(ptx+6.625,pty+3.225),QgsPointXY(ptx+5.825,pty+4.025),QgsPointXY(ptx-5.825,pty+4.025),QgsPointXY(ptx-6.625,pty+3.225),QgsPointXY(ptx-6.625,pty-3.225),QgsPointXY(ptx-5.825,pty-4.025),QgsPointXY(ptx+5.825,pty-4.025),QgsPointXY(ptx+6.625,pty-3.225)]])
        centroid = pol.centroid().asPoint()
        pol.rotate(rad[0]*57.295779513-90, centroid)
        #add geometry to layer
        vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:6348", "temp", "memory")
        pr=vl.dataProvider()
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setGeometry(pol)
        pr.addFeature(f)
        vl.updateExtents()
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image: polygon to overlay on four centerpoints]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before developing my code, I digitized your points and polygon from your image projected with EPSG:32612. However, there is some distortion because I didn't use exact proportions from your image (I estimated it with the naked eye so, there will be some slightly discrepancies in final result). Initial layers can be observed in following image:

[image]

You pointed out a Multipart polygon geometry but, I also used a singlepart polygon geometry for better estimating centroids of mini polygons (in my case, features 0, 1, 3, 4). However, rotated and translated geometry was Multipart polygon. Rotation angle corresponds to the same for producing a minimum bounding box (angles variable produce two values: adequate value is positive angle; angles[0]). For translation (offset calculation), initial point corresponds to centroid of four mini polygons and final point is centroid of four target points.

Complete code looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np

registry = QgsProject.instance()

points = registry.mapLayersByName('points_for_aligning')
polygon = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon_for_aligning_mp')
polygon_sp = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon_for_aligning')

feat_pol_sp = [ feat for feat in polygon_sp[0].getFeatures() ]

centroids_mini_pol = [ feat_pol_sp[0].geometry().centroid(),
                       feat_pol_sp[1].geometry().centroid(),
                       feat_pol_sp[3].geometry().centroid(),
                       feat_pol_sp[4].geometry().centroid()]

points_geom = [ feat.geometry().asPoint() for feat in points[0].getFeatures() ]
angles = [ 90 - points_geom[i].azimuth(points_geom[i+1]) for i in range(len(points_geom)-2) ]

feat_polygon = [ feat for feat in polygon[0].getFeatures() ]

xf = [ point.x() for point in points_geom ]
yf = [ point.y() for point in points_geom ]

xi = [ point.asPoint().x() for point in centroids_mini_pol ]
yi = [ point.asPoint().y() for point in centroids_mini_pol ]

points_centroid = QgsPointXY(np.mean(xf), np.mean(yf))
points_centroid_mp = QgsPointXY(np.mean(xi), np.mean(yi))

geom = feat_polygon[0].geometry()

xoff = points_centroid.x() - points_centroid_mp.x()
yoff = points_centroid.y() - points_centroid_mp.y()

geom.rotate(angles[0], QgsPointXY(np.mean(xi), np.mean(yi)))

geom.translate(xoff, yoff, 0, 0)

epsg = points[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'polygon',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(feat_polygon)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(geom.asWkt()))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

registry.addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running it in Python console of QGIS 3.18, I got following result. Slightly observed discrepancies were product of bad proportioned image used for digitizing my vector layers.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Rotation angle is related to the difference between points azimuths and centroids of mini polygons. I digitized vector layers again from source image, with its correct proportion, and result was similar to above image with azimuths only based in target points. However, when in the code was used `angles2[0] - angles[1]` instead `angles[0]` as rotation angle, result was as expected (following image).

[image]

Geometrically, it can be interpreted as follows:

[image]

So, complete modified code looks now as follows:

```
import numpy as np

registry = QgsProject.instance()

points = registry.mapLayersByName('points_for_aligning2')
polygon = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon_for_aligning_mp2')
polygon_sp = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon_for_aligning2')

feat_pol_sp = [ feat for feat in polygon_sp[0].getFeatures() ]

centroids_mini_pol = [ feat_pol_sp[0].geometry().centroid(),
                       feat_pol_sp[1].geometry().centroid(),
                       feat_pol_sp[3].geometry().centroid(),
                       feat_pol_sp[4].geometry().centroid()]

centroids_mini_pol_pt = [ pt.asPoint() for pt in centroids_mini_pol ]

points_geom = [ feat.geometry().asPoint() for feat in points[0].getFeatures() ]
angles = [ 90 - points_geom[i].azimuth(points_geom[i+1]) for i in range(len(points_geom)-2) ]
angles2 = [ 90 - centroids_mini_pol_pt[i].azimuth(centroids_mini_pol_pt[i+1]) for i in range(len(centroids_mini_pol_pt)-2) ]

feat_polygon = [ feat for feat in polygon[0].getFeatures() ]

xf = [ point.x() for point in points_geom ]
yf = [ point.y() for point in points_geom ]

xi = [ point.asPoint().x() for point in centroids_mini_pol ]
yi = [ point.asPoint().y() for point in centroids_mini_pol ]

points_centroid = QgsPointXY(np.mean(xf), np.mean(yf))
points_centroid_mp = QgsPointXY(np.mean(xi), np.mean(yi))

geom = feat_polygon[0].geometry()

xoff = points_centroid.x() - points_centroid_mp.x()
yoff = points_centroid.y() - points_centroid_mp.y()

geom.rotate(angles2[0] - angles[1], QgsPointXY(np.mean(xi), np.mean(yi)))

geom.translate(xoff, yoff, 0, 0)

epsg = points[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'polygon',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(feat_polygon)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(geom.asWkt()))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

registry.addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```